# Storing Yii sessions in table

Tags: yii, cdbhttpsession

I have an e-commerce application and I need to save cart session in DB. I have tried with the config as follows:

```
'session' => array(
    'class' => 'CDbHttpSession',
    'autoStart' => false,
    'connectionID' => 'db',
    'sessionTableName' => 'YiiSession',
    'autoCreateSessionTable' => false // for performance reasons
),
```

Table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE YiiSession 
(
    id CHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY, 
    expire INTEGER, 
    data TEXT 
);
```

Login session is saving to DB successfully but no other sessions is saving to table. Is my flow correct? Or do I need to add or modify anything?

Answer (score 0):

Your flow is correct, that YiiSession table will just hold session information. Cart info *could* end up there if the cart info is stored in session. But if you want better access to cart session info, better to use another system.